# Retrieving color of maya shader in api

Tags: c++, api, attributes, shader, maya

I am retrieving shaders in maya c++ api using

```
fn.getConnectedShaders(0,shaders,indices);
```

shaders is an MObjectArray containing each shader of the selected object.
How to extract the ambient color and other attributes from the shader MObject ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the existing plugin code. \devkit\plug-ins\D3DViewportRenderer.cpp, it extracts the "ambientColor" and other attributes.